# Why is there no text being shown while tweeting?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The initial text isn't being shown, did I type something wrong or missing something? I followed a tutorial exactly and no beans.

```
  if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
         TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetComposer=[[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
                                                      [self presentModalViewController:tweetComposer animated:YES];
                                                      [tweetComposer setInitialText:@"#VOX"];
    }
```

I am trying to get this to run on ios5.1

Comment: `setInitialText` Returns a BOOL of YES if successful. What is your return value?

Comment: oh, I do not have a return value, can you show me what you mean just to be sure.

Comment: Documentation on `TWTweetComposeViewController` should show you more on `setInitialText` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I mean, can you show me in terms of code what to do, this is so weird. The social framework doesn't need all this bs.

Comment: Have you looked into the Social.framework available in iOS 6.0 or the Twitter.framework available prior to iOS 6(? In Social.framework 
 `(SLComposeViewController *)composeViewControllerForServiceType:(NSString *)serviceType` with a serviceType of "SLServiceTypeTwitter" is all that you would need to open up a tweet composer window. There are functions in that interface for setting initial text etc.

Comment: @rajagp "trying to get this to run on ios5.1"

Comment: @joe: Yes and I do mention twitter framework for < iOS6. Basically the code needs to test the version of iOS and use the right framework. Twitter framework has been deprecated in favor of Social framework in iOS 6 and above.

Comment: @rajagp Please note that original poster was using Twitter.framework already.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might have to call `setInitialText` before you present the [`TWTweetComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html). so you would have:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
         TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetComposer=[[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
                                                      [tweetComposer setInitialText:@"#VOX"];
                                                      [self presentModalViewController:tweetComposer animated:YES];

    }
```

According to the docs for [TWTweetComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) `setInitialText:` Will return a NO if text does not fit in the currently available character space or **the view was presented to the user**.

Comment: +1 for setting the tweet text before presenting the view controller. You still might want to check the length of the tweet text or the return value of setInitialText: to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, Got confused by the comment chain  ("social framework does not need this bs"comment confused me ) because Social framework also uses a similar setInitialText to set the text. .But yes, the initial text needs to be set prior assuming its length is within limits . So +1.